# How to add values to columns on an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question for homework that I do not quite understand. I am being asked to make a query that will result additional values on the same row, Meaning adding more columns as far as I understand. I have no idea how to do it, Unfortunately answers to existing questions here did not seem to answer my question, Maybe I am missing something (I am an SQL noob).

Here is the question:

> Write a query that returns the following data: a row per date and abtest, where each row has the
>   impressions and clicks for all the variants and for the control. Variants are identified as vrows where
>   variant_id is not zero, Control is identified as rows where the variant_id is 0.
>
> E.g. for the below data, the query will return:
>
> 2018-01-01,2,32323,212,95262,354
>
> 2018-01-01,5,76675,5454,675675,5454
>
> 2018-01-02,2,0,0,7834,99
>
> 2018-01-02,5,0,0,9664,144

Table:
https://i.ibb.co/kVZTyt5/ob.jpg

So far I tried this:

```
SELECT date, abtest_id, impressions, clicks FROM table1 WHERE variant_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY date, abtest_id;
```

And this is the result:

> 2018-01-01    2   5454    11
>
> 2018-01-01    5   76675   5454
>
> 2018-01-02    2   7834    99
>
> 2018-01-02    5   776 12

I don't know how to add more clicks and impressions to the results on the same row, And looking at the example from the question, I don't understand how and why some of these values are there. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server (MSSQL), both databases systems have different SQL dialects.

Comment: But i assume you are using MySQL as your [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) query isn't valid.. Using columns in the select clause which are not in the GROUP BY which is invalid ANSI/ISO SQL 1992.. That is the reason i removed the SQL Server tag because SQL Server will not even execute this query

Comment: Well row 1 of your table doesn't have and variant (variant_id = 0), and result is: 2018-01-01, 2, 32323,212,95262,354; 2 = the test number; 32323 = number of impressions without variants; 95262 (35454 + 54354 +5454) = the total of impressions of the variants; 354 (11 + 222 + 121) = the total of clicks for the variants. So your request just has to add impressions and clicks where rows are variants (WHERE variant_id = 0 OR variant_id = NULL) for an abtest_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me you don't need to add columns or rows to your table.
You need to select data, and make a few sums on some fields.

I would do something along these lines in MySQL (only full group by mode turned off):

```
SELECT t.*,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN variant_id != 0 THEN impressions 
    ELSE 0 
    END) v_impressions,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN variant_id != 0 THEN clicks 
    ELSE 0 
    END) v_clicks
FROM `tests` as t
GROUP BY date, abtest_id;
```

Although there may be a simpler syntax.

This selects the data from the rows where variant_id = 0, it sums impressions and clicks where variant_id != 0 and groups by date and abtest_id.

Answer (score 0):

In all DBMS You can use INSERT  OR UPDATE.

INSERT for add new values
Update for change old values

A Simple Insert syntax is:
    Insert into tableName (column1, column2,...) 
    Values (value1, value2,...)

A Simple Update syntax is:

```
Update TableName
Set Column1=value1, Column2=value2
```

You can use where end of above simple codes

Insert syntax by other table is:
    Insert into tableName (column1, column2,...) 
    select t.column1,t.column2... From tablename2

A Simple Update syntax is:

```
Update TableName
Set Column1=value1, Column2=value2
Where colmn1= myValuse
```